# Where can I find documentation on MvcScaffold package listed on nuPack?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, scaffolding, nuget, nuget-package

I'm trying to find documentation on how to use the MvcScaffold package on nuPack, but I can't find anything anywhere.

I know I have basic intellisense support in the Package Management Console, but I want to do something a little more complicated than your typical scaffolding.

I was hoping there would be some documentation somewhere.

Does anyone know where there is documentation on this package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't seem to find the reference to the actual project either.
Though Scott Hanselman has an example in his [blog post on NuPack](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingNuPackPackageManagementForNETAnotherPieceOfTheWebStack.aspx). The scaffolding is invoked through a simple [power shell script](http://nupackpackages.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/b9c3d3b1184a#PackageSources%2fMvcScaffold%2f1.0%2fTools%2finit.ps1), so you can always refer to that.

There are three commands available:

```
> Get-MvcViewTemplates                 (gets a list of available T4 templates)
> Add-MvcView TemplateName             (creates a view based on a T4 template:
                                        I.E. List, Details, Edit, 
                                        Create or Delete)    
> Scaffold-MvcViews -ModelType MyModel (creates views for the model)
```

The example above uses only the mandatory parameters, but you can use any of the additional parameters:

```
> Add-MvcView Edit -ModelType Product -OutputFileExtension .ascx
```

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to find a package listing and I was coming up empty.  That is definitely a big help!

Comment: @Hurricanepkt: yes, it seems that the 0.2 version commands has changed a bit from 0.1 that i posted the link to. The latest version is currently here: http://nupackpackages.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/a30e570cd0bd#PackageSources%2fMvcScaffold%2f0.2%2fTools%2finit.ps1

Answer (score 3):

Steve Sanderson just posted some howtos on his blog about this topic - they're worth reading: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/category/scaffolding/

Answer (score 1):

There's not doc for that package just yet, it's still a prototype you can download the package and look at the source to see all of the options.